# Capture fields values without creating new dummy fields on Case Object

Tags: custom-field, history-tracking, change-data-capture

I have to capture fields values belong 7 different fields when a flag field is true on Case Object  and capture them in object B.

Basically I am trying to avoid creating 7 new fields on Case Object to capture them and retain on Object B.

Is there any other way of doing it without creating new fields on Case Object as we are already hitting limit of maximum fields on Case Object.

Comment: It's not very clear when you say 'capture'. Could you please elaborate? Are you saying the user is going to input 7 values if the flag is true? Or is it a part of automation?

Comment: @Sfdev_CA For Example: When flag is true, Field A has value of xyz, Field B has value of 123. etc. on Case Object. I need to capture and retain those values and show them on object when flag is false.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an object, say, CaseAttributes with fields (CaseId__c, FieldA__c, FieldB__c...)
2. When the flag on Case is set to true, create a record in CaseAttributes, and copy values from Case.FieldA__c to CaseAttributes__c.FieldA__c and so on.
3. Create a lookup to CaseAttribute on Case object. This will help you surface the fields from CaseAttribute when flag is set to false.
4. To surface the values from CaseAttribute record, you can either create an action of type Update Record or use some open source LWC that pulls field values from a lookup record.
5. Set component visibility on this quick action or LWC so that it only shows up when the flag on Case is false.
6. If adding a lookup on Case is not an option, you always have the related list of CaseAttribute on Case

Comment: There is already a Object B created to capture field values when flag is set to false. But now what is happening is now Field values are changing in between flag is set to true and false. Now I need to capture values when the Field is true and populate them when flag is false record is created on Object B.